# "function foo(bar) { }" versus "foo = function(bar) { }"

Tags: javascript, function, variables

```
function foo(bar) {
    // ...
}
```

and

```
foo = function(bar) {
    // ...
};
```

What is the benefit of one versus the other?  The main benefit I see in the latter is not running into errors with a function name already being defined.  However, there may be other benefits or drawbacks that aren't obvious.  What are they (if any)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been asked a few times, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) seems to be the best one.

Answer (score 1):

There are other things that you can do with an anonymous function other than assigning it to a variable. You can for example execute it right away:

```
(function() { ... })();
```

This is sometimes used to create a scope for the code. Anything declared in the scope is local to it, and you can return a result to the code outside:

```
var a = (function() {

  var answer = 42;

  function display() { window.alert(answer); };

  return display;

})();
```

Now the variable `a` contains a function that displays the value of the variable `answer`, but the variable `answer` is local to the scope:

```
a(); // displays the value
display(); // not available
window.alert(answer); // not available
```

This pattern is for example used to create plugins for jQuery:

```
(function($) {

  $.fn.blackText = function() {
    return this.css('color', '#000');
  };

}(jQuery);
```

The `jQuery` object is sent into the scope as the `$` parameter, that way the code in the scope can use the `$` shortcut even if it has been turned off (using `noConflict`) outside the scope.